# How to extract substrings from multiple delimiters like '\' in SQL Server 2014?

Tags: sql, substring

I have a string like this '/1064_MyHoldings/ONLINE/Adhoc/Rpt_CompanyCodeElig'
i just want to extract '1064_MyHoldings' only like wise there are different strings like this where i just want 1st part of string between the first two delimiters?

```
select 
    left(Applications, Len(Path) - CHARINDEX('/', Applications) + 1) FolderName 
from 
    (select distinct 
         Substring(C.Path, CHARINDEX('/', C.Path) + 1, LEN(C.Path) - CHARINDEX('/', C.Path)) Applications) Result
```

where Applications is the column name having data like '/1064_MyHoldings/ONLINE/Adhoc/Rpt_CompanyCodeElig'

Expected result should Be '1064_MyHoldings' that is only the first part of string between the first two '/'

Comment: if you can put more info, such as source string is xxxxx, and the expected string is yyy, that would help people to understand you better.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen added a vivid description to the problem

Comment: You should strive to work with normalized data in SQL. Using delimited strings to store multiple different data points in the same column, argument or variable is really a bad practice for many reasons - read about them [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad).

Comment: @ZoharPeled There are use cases where storing a path in a database table is not necessarily bad practice.  For example, it could be coming from the application layer (but, in that case, it might make more sense to handle this requirement _in_ the application layer).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen A path is not a delimited string. Admittedly, it might be my fault to not recognize the string in the question as a path - however a path is one (composite) data point. That wasn't the case I was talking about. I was talking about stuff like storing `1,2,3,4` or `a/b/c/d` where each part of the delimited string is an "item".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can leverage the base string functions here.  For example, to find the substring contained within the first two `/`, we can try:

```
WITH yourTable AS (
    SELECT '/1064_MyHoldings/ONLINE/Adhoc/Rpt_CompanyCodeElig' AS Path
)

SELECT
    CASE WHEN Path LIKE '%/%/%' THEN
    SUBSTRING(Path,
              CHARINDEX('/', Path) + 1,
              CHARINDEX('/', Path, CHARINDEX('/', Path) + 1) - CHARINDEX('/', Path) - 1)
         ELSE 'NA' END AS first_component
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo

What makes the above logic possible, for the first path component as well as potentially any component, is that `CHARINDEX` has an optional third parameter which lets us specify the starting position to search for a separator `/`.

Note: If you are certain that the first character of `Path` would *always* be just a `/`, then there is a much simpler query you could use:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN Path LIKE '%/%/%'
         THEN SUBSTRING(Path, 2, CHARINDEX('/', Path, 2) - 2)
         ELSE 'NA' END AS first_component
FROM yourTable;
```

But, this would only work again if you know that `/` be the first character in the path.  Otherwise, you would need to use the more verbose version above.

Comment: It is throwing error as 'Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function'.

Comment: @AditiSingh this can only mean that some of your strings contain less than two delimiters.

Comment: @AditiSingh Zohar is correct, and most likely you have at least one path in there with _less_ than two `/`.  I updated my answer to return `NA` for those paths with less than two delimiters.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes some of the strings have only one delimiters.

Answer (score 1):

An ugly, but potentially more flexible approach building off of Tim's answer where you can specify which part of the string you want. **I updated this solution to work with strings that may not start with a delimiter.**

```
with cte1 as (select '1064_MyHoldings/' as Path)

,cte2 as (select case when left(Path,1)<>'/' then  '/'+ Path else Path end as Path from cte1)

select  case when Path like '%/%/%'
         then cast('<x>'+replace(Path,'/','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).value(N'/x[2]','varchar(50)')
         else right(Path,len(Path)-1) end as first_component
from cte2
```

The `x[2]` parameter is what you would change to get different parts of the string. It started with `2` because you have a delimiter before the string. Following the logic, `x[3]` would get you 'ONLINE' for you example string. The `ELSE` is not set to 'NA' because I thought you would want the first element of your string when you have less than 2 delimiters.

Comment: @MeckelsDiverticulum really a flexible approach

Comment: @AditiSingh I modified it a little bit so it also works with strings that don't start with a delimiter.

Comment: @MeckelsDiverticulum it was a wow approach thanks alot it already solved my all upcoming scenarios....my future is sorted thanks Meck (: